# Object inmutable in react-native

Tags: react-native, sockets

I have to pass the object options to create a socket connection, it is created and used like this:

```
        var options = {port: 4444, host: this.props.ip, reuseAddress: true};

        var client = TcpSocket.createConnection(options);
```

But I get the following error:

```
        You attempted to set the key 'host' with the value x.x.x.x on an object that is meant to be inmutable and has been frozen.
```

How can I clone or copy the ip (received as a prop by the child component) so I don't get this error?

**Edit:** I have tried this, but same error appears.

```
var self = this;
var clone = Object.assign({}, self.props)

var options = {port: 4444, host:clone.ip, reuseAddress: true};
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the components that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

I have to create 2 sockets, if I use the same options object, it throws that error.
Copying the object and passing a different object to the second socket solved the issue.